# how to setup VM with debootstrap

Tags: xen, guest

I'm having problems to configure a virtual machine with xen server.

following tutorial I made this steps:

1. make the lvm partitions (root, swap) on my host and format
2. mount root partition on /mnt
3. debootstrap --arch amd64 precise /mnt http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
4. create `.cfg` file

   ```
   memory     = 1024
   vcpus      = 1
   name       = "testdomain"
   vif        = [' ']
   disk       = ['phy:/dev/<VG>/testdomain_root,sda1,w', 'phy:/dev/<VG>/testdomain_swp,sda2,w']
   root       = "/dev/sda1 ro"
   extra      = "console=hvc0"
   ```
5. unmount the partition
6. finally execute `xm create -c testdomain.crg`

but always tell me that bootloader don't return anything

where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you unmount after running debootstrap?

Comment: obviously umount the partition :)

Comment: Are you using xen-tools?